# How to manage conditional colunm in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have the same problem than [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941673/sql-conditional-relationships).

But in my case I dont have tables, I have only two colums. I explain:

```
***mytable
id
name
conditional_1 (is a foreign key int)
conditional_2 (int)
```

The data contained would be like this:

```
id  name   conditional_1  conditional_2
1   oscar  1              NULL
2   rene   NULL           67
3   hello  2              NULL
4   stack  4              NULL
5   overf  NULL           98
```

I'm doing it right? or I would need something like the following:

```
***mytable
id
name
cond_type 
conditional_id (fk tbl_post)

***condtable1
conditional_1 

***condtable1
conditional_2
```

What would be the best solution for this case?

Comment: Didn't you like the answer to the question you linked to? Looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using columns in the same table you can enforce both the exclusivity and the referential integrity. In other words, you can ensure that in a given row at most one of the fields is non-NULL<sup>1</sup> *and* references the existing row from the correct table. Alternatively, you could consider inheritance. For more on both, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120).

Something like `cond_type` bears no meaning from the DBMS perspective - you'll be forgoing the automatic enforcement of the referential integrity. And doing it manually in a *concurrent environment* is likely to be either incorrect or slow.<sup>2</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints (that would be a natural mechanism for enforcing exclusivity), but you can still rely on triggers.*

*<sup>2</sup> You'll need to lock very carefully to avoid race conditions, and even if you do it right you'll probably hurt the scalability in the process.*

Comment: Thanks @Branko Dimitrijevic d ! In other words: the first way I posted is correct. (or at least not the ugliest), isn't it?